# Searchable database of members using multiple criteria / filters

Tags: database, search

I'm very new to wp let's say that first!

What I need is to create a site which will list a database of members of an organisation. Users will also be able to sign-up and add themselves to the database.

But additionally I want users to be able to search for other users using given criteria check boxes, for example:

Is male [ ] Is female [ ] Lives in city x [ ] Lives in city y [ ] Lives in city z [ ] Is aged 20-30 [ ] Is aged 30-40 [ ] Is aged 40-50 [ ]

(These arent the criteria I want to use but just examples by the way)

I checked out 'Participants Database' plug-in which looks excellent, all up to the part that I want the search to do the above filtering which it isn't clear how to achieve.

So, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and solved it using the Participants Database plugin. The `pdb_list` shortcode [supports filters](http://xnau.com/work-2/wordpress-plugins/participants-database/using-the-participants-database-plugin/#filtering), e.g. `[pdb_list filter='state=NY']`.

You can generate any shortcodes from a PHP script by running a script with the [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function, like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[pdb_list filter='state=NY']');
```

Now you have all the building blocks you need to generate the list server-side. Check out [this](http://xnau.com/using-participants-database-with-wordpress-users/) article for more details.